# Instantiating objects that need to be injected with Bridge (pattern) objects. How should I do it?

Tags: php, design-patterns, bridge

The context is the following:

I have Job class that represents a Job that is sent to a Job Queue.
Currently we only use SQS for that purpose, but in the future we might migrate to Redis or another MQ solution.
So currently, I have a AbstractJob that can be extended into ConcreteJobOne and ConcreteJobTwo, and can be consumed by AbstractQueueClient (which can be SqsQueueClient). I need a way of getting the payload from a Job object, what I came up was using the [bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern).

```
$parameters = [];
$sqsClient = new AbstractQueueClient();
$jobOne = new ConcreteJobOne($parameters, new SqsPayloadBridge());
$sqsClient->queueSingleJob($jobOne);
```

With that, I'm able to change the way I can build the payload for a specific client.

But the Controller that takes care of queueing that job has to know about SqsPayloadBridge and all the other bridges that might come in the future. I thought about using the Factory pattern to solve this but seems like overkill.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by not using a Bridge at all.

The implementations of AbstractQueueClient will handle a ->toArray() from Job implementations the way they see fit.